# How to Build Stateless Widget from Dynamic Map

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new into flutter, I would like to build dynamic Map<key,value> to a stateless widget. I have tried to use as many tutorials given but it can only works if it is a list. If it is map which contain such as

> final Map toCheck = {'bedroom':'bed','bathroom':'bathtub_outlined'};

It shows an error

> lib/template/general.dart:164:18: Error: A value of type 'Row' can't
> be returned from a function with return type 'MapEntry<dynamic,
> dynamic>'.
>
> - 'Row' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart').
> - 'MapEntry' is from 'dart:core'.
>   return Row(
>   ^ lib/template/general.dart:170:12: Error: The method 'toList' isn't defined for the class 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.
> - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toList'.
>   }).toList(),
>   ^^^^^^

Here is the stateless widget function

```
class BundleSpecification extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map specification;
  BundleSpecification(this.specification);

  final Map toCheck = {'bedroom':'bed','bathroom':'bathtub_outlined'};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15.0, 0, 15.0),
      child: Row(
        children: toCheck.map((type,value){
          return Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.bed),
              Text(specification[value]),
            ],
          );
        }).toList(),
      )
    );
  }
```

I really appreciate any answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Row` takes an `Iterable` (for example a `List`) as argument for `children`. You provide it a map which obviously does not work.

Comment: so, how about doing foreach inside children of Row? What approach do you suggest anyway?

Comment: see @esentis answer

Comment: Hi, do you know how to set Icon(Icons.bed) to Icon(Icons.[callVariable])?

Answer (score 0):

You can try mapping the `Map` in your `Row` widget this way:

```dart
Row(
 children: [
  ...toCheck.entries.map(
   (x) => Row(
     children: [
       Icon(Icons.bed),
       Text(specification[x.value]),
    ],
   ),
  )
 ],
)
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to set Icon(Icons.bed) into dynamic. How to approach Icon(Icons.[x.key])

Comment: I don't think you can. You'll have to manually handle your cases in a function e.g `if (x.key=='bed') return Icons.bed`

Comment: I see, I thought it could be called from dynamic var. Thank you